# Problema al comparar las letras una a una de dos cadenas

Tags: java

Hola el problema dice así:

> Crea una clase en cuyo método main ejecutes una comparación letra a letra usando equals de dos palabras usando bucles.
>
> Por ejemplo si las palabras son `“avispa”` y `“ave”` el programa debe dar como resultado:
>   ¿Letra 1 igual en las dos palabras? `True`.
>   ¿Letra 2 igual en las dos palabras? `True`
>   ¿Letra 3 igual en las dos palabras? `False`
>   ¿Letra 4 igual en las dos palabras? `La palabra 2 no tiene letra 4`
>   ¿Letra 5 igual en las dos palabras? `La palabra 2 no tiene letra 5`
>   ¿Letra 6 igual en las dos palabras? `La palabra 2 no tiene letra 6`.

Yo lo intento así (Aclaro que debe ser orientado a objetos):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Introduce palabra 1: ");
    Entrega662 cadena1=new Entrega662();
    System.out.println("Ingrese palabra 2: ");
    Entrega662 cadena2=new Entrega662();

    if(cadena1.getLargo()>cadena2.getLargo()){
        boolean iguales;
        for(int x=0;x<cadena1.getLargo();x++){
            System.out.println("¿Letra "+(x+1)+" igual en las dos palabras");
               if(cadena1.getLetra(x).equals(cadena2.getLetra(x))){
                   iguales=true;
                   System.out.println(iguales);
               }else{
                   iguales=false;
                   System.out.println(iguales);
               }
               if(x>cadena2.getLargo()){
                   System.out.println("Cadena 2 no tiene letra "+(x+1));
               }

        }
    }
```

Miren el resultado que me da:

> ```
> Introduce palabra 1: 
> Avispa
> Ingrese palabra 2: 
> Ave
> ¿Letra 1 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> ¿Letra 2 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> ¿Letra 3 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> ¿Letra 4 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> ¿Letra 5 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> Cadena 2 no tiene letra 5
> ¿Letra 6 igual en las dos palabras
> true
> Cadena 2 no tiene letra 6
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Modifique un poco el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduce palabra 1: ");
        Entrega662 cadena1 = new Entrega662();
        System.out.println("Ingrese palabra 2: ");
        Entrega662 cadena2 = new Entrega662();

        if (cadena1.getLargo() > cadena2.getLargo()) {
            boolean iguales = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < cadena1.getLargo(); x++) {

                if (x < cadena2.getLargo()) {
                    System.out.println("¿Letra " + (x + 1) + " igual en las dos palabras?");
                    if (cadena1.getLetra(x).equals(cadena2.getLetra(x))) {
                        iguales = true;
                        System.out.println(iguales);
                    } else if (iguales == true) {
                        iguales = false;
                        System.out.println(iguales);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Cadena 2 no tiene letra " + (x + 1));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que hice fue agregar un if para ver si la  variable x aun era mas pequeña que cadena2 ya que si seguia haciendo la comparacion marcaba un *StringIndexOutOfBoundsException* por que la cadena 2 es mas chica, si aun era mas chica haria la comparación si no manda al mensaje de que ya no contiene la letra.

Salida en consola:

```
Introduce palabra 1: 
avispa
Ingrese palabra 2: 
ave
¿Letra 1 igual en las dos palabras?
true
¿Letra 2 igual en las dos palabras?
true
¿Letra 3 igual en las dos palabras?
false
Cadena 2 no tiene letra 4
Cadena 2 no tiene letra 5
Cadena 2 no tiene letra 6
```

Espero te pueda ayudar.